# Using Cramer's rule for a system of equations with four variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant

Given the following system of equations:
\begin{align*}
w + x + y &= 3 \\
x + y + z &= 4 \\
x + y + 2z &= 10 \\
w + x + z &= 20
\end{align*}
Find $w$ using Cramer's rule.
Answer:
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} - \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} \\
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} -
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{vmatrix} = 1 - (1 - 2) + (0 - 1) \\
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &= 1 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &= 
- \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{vmatrix} = -(0 - 2) + (0-1) = 1 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &= 
- \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} = - ( 0 - 2) + (0 - 1) = 1 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &= 1 - 1 + 1 = 1 \\
w &= \frac{
 \begin{vmatrix}
 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 6 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
 20 & 1 & 0 & 1
 \end{vmatrix}
} { 1 } = \begin{vmatrix}
3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
6 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
20 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} \\
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
6 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
20 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &= 3 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} -
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 1 & 1 \\
6 & 1 & 2 \\
20 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 1 & 1 \\
6 & 1 & 2 \\
20 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} = ( 0 - 1(-1) ) \\
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &= 1 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 1 & 1 \\
6 & 1 & 2 \\
20 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &= 4 \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} -
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & 2 \\
20 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}
6 & 1 \\
20 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 4(1-2) - (6 - 40) + 6 - 20 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 1 & 1 \\
6 & 1 & 2 \\
20 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &= 4(-1) - 6 + 40 + 6 - 20 = 16 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 1 & 1 \\
6 & 1 & 2 \\
20 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &= 
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & -4 & -4 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 4
\begin{vmatrix} 
-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
-4 & -4 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 4( 2 + 2 ) = 16 \\
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
6 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
20 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} &= 3( 1 ) - 16 + 16 = 3 \\
W &= \frac{3}{1} \\
W &= 3
\end{align*}
I have good reason to solution this system of equations is:
 $(w,x,y,z) = (5,9,-11,6)$

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:
$$w= \frac{
 \begin{vmatrix}
 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 10 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
 20 & 1 & 0 & 1
 \end{vmatrix}
} { 1 }=$$

$$
= 3 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} -
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 1 & 2 \\
20 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}
4 & 1 & 1 \\
10 & 1 & 2 \\
20 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=
$$
$$=3(1+2+0-1-1-0)-(4+40+0-20-10-0)+$$
$$+(4+40+10-20-10-8)=3-14+16=5.$$